# nestjs 9: problem with inject after upgrade from version 8 to 9

Tags: nestjs

I do have a problem after updating my nestjs app from version 8 to 9.

I try it with an empty project to be able to reproduce it with the same error.

- nest new [projectname]

I did also update everything to the latest version to ensure all fixes are included.

adding the following code into the appModule.ts

```js
import { Inject, Injectable, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

// constants as names for the services to inject later on other services. Specific the configService is required by name
const dbService = 'dbService';
const configService = 'configService';

@Injectable()
export class DbService {
  dummyMethod(correlationId: number | undefined): void {
    console.log('start dummyMethod', correlationId);
    console.log('end dummyMethod', correlationId);
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {
  constructor(@Inject(dbService) protected readonly db: DbService) {}

  async initDatabase(correlationId: number | undefined): Promise<void> {
    console.log('start initDatabase', correlationId);
    this.db.dummyMethod(correlationId);
    console.log('end initDatabase', correlationId);
  }
}

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    {
      provide: dbService,
      useClass: DbService,
    },
    {
      provide: configService,
      useClass: AppConfigService,
--> the dbService get the error: TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
      inject: [dbService],
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I could not find anything on the change log that was for me understandable that this has changed.

If someone has an idea what has changed and, even more appreciated :-), how can I fix it  would be really nice.

Thank you very much.

Dirk

Comment: I found the explanation:
Since Version 9 there are more strict type configurations available. In my case the combination of useClass and inject is not working.

Solution was easy:
instea uf useClass i have to use useFactory...

Wonder why it was working in the past :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're using `inject` along with `useClass` and this is invalid. `inject` is only for `useFactory` (ie., factory provider), it has no effect on others custom providers. Just drop it.

btw this is the same behavior of v8, v9 just report that.

Comment: Yes, I just realized it after writing the sample an retry it again. As usual: just writing it down sometimes helps a lot. thank you

The problem was that in v8 there was no error show me that I do someting wrong :-) So today I'm wondering why my app was working in this way :-)

Comment: @dide, your app was working because in this case it matters only for TypeScript checking, not for runtime JavaScript.

Comment: exactly. And that change isn't in the migration guide because that `inject`+`useClasse` isn't valid in first place (ie., there's no mention on that in the docs of v8).

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { Inject, Injectable, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

// constants as names for the services to inject later on other services. Specific the configService is required by name
const dbService = 'dbService';
const configService = 'configService';

@Injectable()
export class DbService {
  dummyMethod(correlationId: number | undefined): void {
    console.log('start dummyMethod', correlationId);
    console.log('end dummyMethod', correlationId);
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {
  constructor(@Inject(dbService) protected readonly db: DbService) {}

  async initDatabase(correlationId: number | undefined): Promise<void> {
    console.log('start initDatabase', correlationId);
    this.db.dummyMethod(correlationId);
    console.log('end initDatabase', correlationId);
  }
}

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    {
      provide: dbService,
      useClass: DbService,
    },
    {
      provide: configService,
      **useFactory: (dbService: DbService) => new AppConfigService(dbService),**
      inject: [dbService],
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```